# Redirecting a file as input and reading/storing its data in C

Tags: c, file-io, arguments, argv

I am trying to to redirect a file to be read through stdin, which should look like this:

```
./a.out < filename
```

And the contents of the file are as follows:

```
12.3456
23.4567
34.5678
```

And so on, with one float on each line.

I'm having some issues conceptually as well as with the actual code.  My first attempt to read it was with File I/O, but that did not work.  Since it's being fed directly to stdin, I won't need it, as far as I understand.  Then, I tried something like this:

```
char temp_str[10];
float temp_float;

FILE *stdin;

while(!feof(stdin))   //It seg faults right here
{
    fgets(temp_str, 10, stdin);
    temp_float = atof(temp_str);      //This stuff worked when I read it using FILE IO,
                                  //but it's causing trouble in this example
    printf("%.4f\n", temp_float);     
}
```

However, I can't tell if it's close or if I'm misunderstanding what, exactly, is happening.

Any clarifications/suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: 1) Delete `FILE *stdin;`.

Comment: Wow, that simple.  Thank you!